# Linear Projections vs Linear Decompositions

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Is it true that (proof?):
$T^2=T\iff\mathcal{D}(T)=\mathcal{R}(T)\oplus\mathcal{N}(T)$ with $T\text{ linear}$

*The forward direction I already proved. Missing only the direction backwards...*

Comment: What is $\mathcal{D}(T)$? I assume $\mathcal{R}$ and $\mathcal{N}$ are the range and null space?

Comment: Yes and domain ;)

Comment: It's not true, then: There are isomorphisms of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with itself that don't satisfy the desired property.

Comment: Oh s###, I just realized its wrong: $T:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3:(a,b,c)\mapsto(b,a,0)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The claim is false, and there are actually counterexamples in any vector space of dimension $\ge 1$. Choose any isomorphism $T$ which is not the identity; then $\mathcal{N}(T) = 0$ and $\mathcal{R}(T) = V = \mathcal{D}(T)$. Since $T$ is an isomorphism,

$$T^2 = T \iff T^{-1} T^2 = T^{-1} T \iff T = I$$

Answer (score 1):

The converse is wrong, e.g.: $T:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3:(a,b,c)\mapsto(b,a,0)$